# In JQuery tablesorter - How do I change parser according to the sort order

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using jQuery tablesorter on a table that has columns with comma separated number content. I added a Custom Parser and that solves my problem of sorting the comma formatted numbers.
I want a special case, the value 'NA' to always be at the end of the sorted column, irrespective of the sort order. One way of doing that I figured is to "tweak" the Custom Parser I'm using in some way, like in the comment of below code.

```
 $.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'number-sorter',
    is: function (s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s) {
        return s.replace(/,/g, '');

        /* what I want here is -
        if(sortOrder == "asc")
            return s.replace(/,/g, '').replace('NA', Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        else
            return s.replace(/,/g, '').replace('NA', Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
        */

    },
    type: 'numeric'
});
```

I'm having problem with determining the sort order (the variable that I'm assuming 'sortOrder').
Or is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798504/tablesorter-custom-parser-dependent-on-sorting-type, if you share an example, I might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, from what it appears you are trying to do is sort non-numbers at the bottom of the table. I have a [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) that has an [option named `stringTo`](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#stringto) which allows you to set where you want strings (non-numeric values) to sort: 'max', 'min', 'top', 'bottom', 'none' (treats a string as a number with the value of zero); so in your case, set the value to 'max'.

[Check out the demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers-digits-strings.html)